# Search subdocuments in ElasticSearch with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch

Suppose I have a series of embedded or child documents that I'd like to search on, but return their parents as my results, like Buildings and Units:

```
Building A
- Unit 1F
- Unit 1R
- Unit 2F: 1200 sq ft
- Unit 2R: 2300 sq ft

Building B
- Unit 202: 500 sq ft
- Unit 203: 650 sq ft
```

Now suppose I want to return all buildings that have units >= 1000 sq ft. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the unit sizes as an Array:

```
class Building

  def search_data
    {
      # ... other fields
      unit_sq_ft: units.map(&:sq_ft)
    }
  end

end
```

and search with:

```
Building.search "pool", where: {unit_sq_ft: {gte: 1000}}
```

Comment: How about if you have multiple attributes for each unit, like sq_ft, bedrooms, bathrooms, description

Comment: Nested document search is pretty limited right now. You can search for building with at least one unit w/ X sq ft and one unit w/ Y bedrooms, but you can't search for a building that has one unit w/ X sq ft AND the same unit has Y bedrooms.