# Find all children of user with Searchkick

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to find all records of children account of a given user.

What I have right now:

```
@parent = @user.id
@children = User.search ("*"), 
  page: params[:page], per_page: 20, 
    # Discard account that don't have coordinates to avoid distance errors
    where: {
      coordinates: {not: nil},
      role: :organization,
      parent_id: @parent
    },
    order: {_geo_distance: {coordinates: {lat: @coordinates[1], lon: @coordinates[0]}, order: "asc", unit: "mi"} }
```

This runs the following query:

```
curl http://localhost:1234/users_development/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "not": {
              "filter": {
                "missing": {
                  "field": "coordinates",
                  "existence": true,
                  "null_value": true
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "role": "organization"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "parent_id": {
                "$oid": "44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {
    "_geo_distance": {
      "coordinates": {
        "lat": -118.3919,
        "lon": 34.1379
      },
      "order": "asc",
      "unit": "mi"
    }
  },
  "fields": []
}'
```

When I look up one of the children users in the console, I see this for the parent_id: `<BSON::ObjectId:0x70205146889309 data=44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310>`

The query I run gives `Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures...`

I'm pretty sure I'm mistyping the query somehow. What's the correct syntax?

Here's the full error:

```
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[MRKTgyLfTGSnADDAIoMdLg][users_development_20151220094401447][0]: SearchParseException[[users_development_20151220094401447][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"not\":{\"filter\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"coordinates\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},{\"term\":{\"role\":\"organization\"}},{\"term\":{\"parent_id\":{\"$oid\":\"44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310\"}}}]}}},\"size\":20,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":-118.3919,\"lon\":34.1379},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"mi\"}},\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[users_development_20151220094401447] [term] filter does not support [$oid]]; }{[MRKTgyLfTGSnADDAIoMdLg][users_development_20151220094401447][1]: SearchParseException[[users_development_20151220094401447][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"not\":{\"filter\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"coordinates\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},{\"term\":{\"role\":\"organization\"}},{\"term\":{\"parent_id\":{\"$oid\":\"44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310\"}}}]}}},\"size\":20,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":-118.3919,\"lon\":34.1379},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"mi\"}},\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[users_development_20151220094401447] [term] filter does not support [$oid]]; }{[MRKTgyLfTGSnADDAIoMdLg][users_development_20151220094401447][2]: SearchParseException[[users_development_20151220094401447][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"not\":{\"filter\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"coordinates\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},{\"term\":{\"role\":\"organization\"}},{\"term\":{\"parent_id\":{\"$oid\":\"44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310\"}}}]}}},\"size\":20,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":-118.3919,\"lon\":34.1379},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"mi\"}},\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[users_development_20151220094401447] [term] filter does not support [$oid]]; }{[MRKTgyLfTGSnADDAIoMdLg][users_development_20151220094401447][3]: SearchParseException[[users_development_20151220094401447][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"not\":{\"filter\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"coordinates\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},{\"term\":{\"role\":\"organization\"}},{\"term\":{\"parent_id\":{\"$oid\":\"44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310\"}}}]}}},\"size\":20,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":-118.3919,\"lon\":34.1379},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"mi\"}},\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[users_development_20151220094401447] [term] filter does not support [$oid]]; }{[MRKTgyLfTGSnADDAIoMdLg][users_development_20151220094401447][4]: SearchParseException[[users_development_20151220094401447][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"not\":{\"filter\":{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"coordinates\",\"existence\":true,\"null_value\":true}}}},{\"term\":{\"role\":\"organization\"}},{\"term\":{\"parent_id\":{\"$oid\":\"44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310\"}}}]}}},\"size\":20,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"coordinates\":{\"lat\":-118.3919,\"lon\":34.1379},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"mi\"}},\"fields\":[]}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[users_development_20151220094401447] [term] filter does not support [$oid]]; }]","status":400}):
```

Comment: Can you add the full error you're seeing, especially what comes after `shardFailures`?

Comment: Sure. Added to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error

```
[term] filter does not support [$oid]]
```

The issue lies in the following part

```
      {
        "term": {
          "parent_id": {
            "$oid": "44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310"
          }
        }
      }
```

You simply need to write it like this:

```
      {
        "term": {
          "parent_id": "44fa9f8962656e0404bd3310"
        }
      }
```

Comment: My question is how you write that with searchkick. Obviously, I am aware that I need to match the parent_id field to the parent's id. Adding "parent_id: @parent" to the "where" clause does not work. Adding "term: {parent_id: @parent}" also doesn't. Adding "term: {parent_id: @parent}" AFTER the "where" clause doesn't work either.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646223/ruby-model-output-id-as-object-oid) could well be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help. Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544048/search-subdocuments-in-elasticsearch-with-searchkick didn't help. I posted the question as an issue on github and hope to hear back. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: For those willing to follow, the issue @Ben posted is here: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/589